# GWT Code Validation with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When I open my GWT project it always validates GWT Java code (`.java` and `.ui.xml`), my project is quite large in code so it takes very long time for the validation to complete. How do I control this validation process, so I won't validate everything every time I open my project?

From the eclipse console I can see that the longest time to validate are those ui.xml codes like:

```
MYPROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/client/core/view/MainView.ui.xml
```

Comment: Did you try disabling validation in preferences? Check this [help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjvaldisable.html) provided by eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of the ui.xml file there would be following line of code. Please put in comment. It wil reduce time in validation as well as fetching resources.

```
 <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the errors or if you can post over here it would be better.

Comment: As I remember the exact error, Eclipse is complaining, looking for that <!DOCTYPE...> tag in the ui.xml codes

Comment: As far as I know, This should not happen unless and until if you have used any HTML codes directly in ui.xml. Please remove them and then compile it.