# Validating GWT components takes forever

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Validating GWT components process in Eclipse takes ages, almost impossible to do productive work. I have selected from my `Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Validators`: selected `Supend all validators` still Eclipse validates GWT components which is painfully slow. How can I fix this? It's very hard when eclipse just validates the whole application every time I save.

Comment: Are you sure that's even related?  What are you seeing in the Progress View?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT Code Validation with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388560/gwt-code-validation-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same phenomenon. Upgrading to Eclipse Juno/4.2 fixed the problem for us.

Another possible solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388560/gwt-code-validation-with-eclipse#answer-11389095).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this solved the issue:

Right click project -> properties -> JavaScript -> Include Path

Then add an Exclude path to your compiled GWT files like this. You dont need to validate them:

[image]