# Eclipse Juno + WTP +EGit dead slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, eclipse-wtp

I'm trying to use Eclipse Juno (Version: 4.2.0 Build id: I20120608-1400) with WTP for JavaScript/Node.js development on MacOSX Lion, on my 4GB RAM MacBook Pro. Sometimes it gets dead slow, and unusable. I've tried tweaking both through preferences (disabled all validators) and initialization variables, and also upgraded to 1.7 VM as recommended. Here's the contents of my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms64m
-Xmx256m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-server
```

Can someone advise what I could do to improve WTP performance?

Comment: Why is your maximum heap size set to 256MB?  That's half of the default for Juno.

Comment: I've increased the 256m properties to 512m and 64m to 128m (Default on MacOS is 256m for Juno, except -Xmx384m). I've disabled all validators, all highlights. What I have now looks like notepad with syntax highlighting, and it still hangs and uses 361% of CPU and loads of RAM. I'm pretty sure this is a problem with WTP.

Comment: @recidive FWIW, After testing Eclipse (JEE packaging) for a week, I went back to Indigo. It seems that there is a severe overall performance issue in Juno. My colleague who used the Java developer packaging came to the same conclusions.

Comment: it is interesting why Eclipse team concentrates on unnecessary appearance changes instead of the most important for all developers: performance. When you put in google: "Eclipse is" the very first suggestion is "Eclipse is SLOW".

Answer (score 9):

unfortunately i can second that. juno is unusable slow in comparison to indigo. with every click i have to wait multiple seconds for a reaction of the gui. i too can exclude the reason might be on the side of my hardware.

Answer (score 6):

Please see the comments on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272.

We're aware that there is an issue here but are as yet unsure as to what the cause is. We're in the act of profiling various scenarios to try to get a handle on why some people see such a significant degradation while most seem to work at least acceptably.

Please post information on the defect above about what features you're using there, maybe it'll help up track down the culprit...no smiley, this is serious.

Comment: I'd like to share my experience with Juno but I cannot find a way to register a new account with bugs.eclipse.org. There is just a login form for existing users.

Answer (score 5):

I encounter the same issue, and seems to be solved by select the checkbox "Use virtual memory mapping", you can see the option on,
**Preference-->Team-->Git-->Window Cache**

Comment: Can confirm this improves the speed of Eclipse Juno significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Found a [a bug report (id : 385272)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272) raised for slow Juno response times.

Comment: Point 2, renaming workbench.xmi, from [Comment 29](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272#c29) by Brian does have an perceivable difference on the response times.

Comment: But it only lasted for few hours and seemed to cause new slowdowns later.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [official performance patch for Juno SR1](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation#Resolution). Otherwise you could switch to Juno SR2 or [Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different perspective (the Resource one, for example) and restart Eclipse.

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue is only happening in the PHP perspective. Launching Eclipse Juno in a different perspective and then switching to the PHP perspective made the tab switching reasonable.

A less cumbersome and permanent solution exists, which is quite straightforward.
Installing Web Development Tools fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an unofficial patch, which makes switching between editors a lot faster. See this comment:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391868#c28

You just add the referenced page http://www.objectteams.org/EclipsePatch422beta/, and it seems to be a lot faster. Unofficial patch, so backup your Eclipse before.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable validation of your Node.js and other JavaScript libs as they should be validated by their providers. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909401/1040124